# Youtube API for Android - Creating Multiple Thumbnails

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

For some reason all my thumbnails appear the same. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong but I'm sure one of you can spot the issue (it is my first time using the Youtube API)

Any suggestions?

P.S.

I think this may have to do with the fact I'm using youTubeThumbnailView1 and youTubeThumbnailView2 to create multiple thumbnails - however I have a feeling this might not be the correct way of doing so.

### SCREENSHOT:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEWKK.png

### JAVA:

```
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyC0Te2pyooXzuyLaE6_SsFlITKCwjj55fI";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    public static final String VIDEO1_ID = "xVHHJqntuXI";
    public static final String VIDEO2_ID = "YWteQj_q3Ro";

    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView1;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView2;

    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        mainScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);



        youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
        youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });




        youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
        youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        youTubePlayer = player;

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

        youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
        thumbnailLoader
        .setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO_ID);

    }

    private final class ThumbnailLoadedListener implements
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, ErrorReason arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String arg1) {

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this function:

```
 @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

    youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
    thumbnailLoader
    .setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

    //You are always loading the thumbnail of VIDEO_ID
    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO_ID);

}
```

You are always loading the thumbnail of VIDEO_ID. You should check which view has initialized. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

    youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
    thumbnailLoader
    .setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

    if (thumnailView.equals(youTubeThumbnailView1)
       youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
    else
       youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO2_ID);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are calling `youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);` for both youTubeThumbnailView1 and youTubeThumbnailView2.

Comment: That will change the video played... not the thumbnail displayed. I've tried changing it - it does nothing.

Comment: I still need help with this if anyone has any suggestions... the answer above does not resolve the issue